# Colores random en C

Tags: c

Tengo una duda con este programita de C, es muy simple y básico, se genera un número aleatorio del 1 al 10 y lee un valor por carga de usuario. Si el usuario acierta, me gustaría hacer que la consola cambie de colores random diciendo "ACERTASTE"... Pero no se me ocurre cómo, pues la función system("color") está hecha para mantener un color fijo...
Alguna idea? Yo sé que "código compartido es código a ser bastardeado" pero recién empiezo en esto xDD acepto críticas constructivas

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
 
int RandomMin1Max10();
int CargaNum();
 
int main()
{
    /*llamar a la función random con mínimo  1 y máximo 10*/
    int bing; /**Número entre 1 y 10 generado aleatoriamente**/
    int bong; /**Número del usuario**/
 
    system("color 0C");
 
    bing = RandomMin1Max10();
 
    do
    {
        bong = CargaNum();
 
    }while (bong != bing);
 
}
 
int RandomMin1Max10()
{
    #include <time.h>
 
    srand(time(NULL));
    int valor;
 
    valor = (rand()%(10+1-1)+1);
 
    return valor;
}
 
int CargaNum()
{
    int num;
    puts("Ingrese su numero!\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
 
    return num;
}
```

Comment: *"acepto críticas constructivas"*. Solo unas cuantas notas. 1. No coloques un `#include` dentro de una función, colócalo hasta arriba con los demas. 2. En lugar de ser `int RandomMin1Max10()`, es mas flexible que escribas `int Random(int min, int max)`. Eso ara mas general tu codigo y ayudara a que sea reutilizable.

Comment: Duda, cuando dices que quieres que cambie de colores random te refieres a que la consola en general cambie de colores varias veces en poco tiempo? Si es eso, porque no llamar en un loop `system("color XY")` randomizando `X` y `Y` cada vez que pasa?

Comment: Pues, qué raro, antes había probado eso que me dices del loop y cambiaba el color pero también me mostraba un mensaje (de Windows) para indicarme los códigos de colores en cada loop y eso quedaba feo. Por alguna razón lo probé de nuevo y ahora solo me cambia los colores, como buscaba.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios! =)

Answer (score 2):

Si estas usando windows Lo puedes hacer con esta función void que te dejo aqui aunque necesitas añadir la librería windows.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

void cambiar_color(int , int );

int main()
{
//primer número para el color del texto y el segundo para el color del fondo.
system("color f0");//pone el fondo blanco y el texto negro es importante para que no importe la configuración que tenga puesta la persona previamente.
printf("prueba fondo blanco y letra negra\n");
cambiar_color(4,15);//cambia el color de la letra y deja el fondo blanco
printf("prueba cambio de color de letra\n");
cambiar_color(0,15);//buelve a poner el color de las letras que se escriban posteriormente a negro otra vez y deja el fondo blanco
system("pause");
}

void cambiar_color(int ForgC, int BackC)
  {
     WORD wColor = ((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) + (ForgC & 0x0F);
     SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), wColor);
     return;
  }
```

Esta es una lista de los colores que puedes poner con sus números:

0 = Negro

1 = Azul

2 = Verde

3 = Aguamarina

4 = Rojo

5 = Purpura

6 = Amarillo

7 = Blanco

8 = Gris

9 = Azul claro

10 = Verde claro

11 = Aguamarina claro

12 = Rojo claro

13 = Purpura claro

14 = Amarillo claro

15 = Blanco brillante

Answer (score 1):

Al final me aburría y he hecho mas o menos lo que querías ahora puedes añadir lo que quieras pero la base funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>


void cambiar_color(int , int );
int color_random();

int RandomMin1Max10();
int CargaNum();

int main()
{
    /*llamar a la función random con mínimo  1 y máximo 10*/
    int bing; /**Número entre 1 y 10 generado aleatoriamente**/
    int bong; /**Número del usuario**/
    int color;
    system("color f0");

    bing = RandomMin1Max10();

    do
    {
        bong = CargaNum();

    }while (bong != bing);

    printf("\n\n");//un par de saltos de linea porque queda más bonito XD

    if(bong == bing)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        color=color_random();//genera un número aleatorio correspondiente a un color y filtra el blanco y el gris.
        cambiar_color(color,15);//defino un color para cada letra para que sea multicolor.
        printf("A");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("C");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("E");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("R");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("T");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("A");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);;
        printf("S");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("T");

        color=color_random();
        cambiar_color(color,15);
        printf("E\n");

        cambiar_color(0,15);//reestablezco los colores que había al principio
        system("pause");
    }
}

int RandomMin1Max10()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int valor;

    valor = (rand()%(10+1-1)+1);

    return valor;
}

int CargaNum()
{
    int num;
    puts("Ingrese su numero!\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    return num;
}

void cambiar_color(int ForgC, int BackC)
  {
     WORD wColor = ((BackC & 0x0F) << 4) + (ForgC & 0x0F);
     SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), wColor);
     return;
  }

  int color_random()
  {
      int color;

      color = (rand()%(10+1-1)+1);//hace color aleatorio entre el 1 y el 10

      if((color==7)||(color==8))//si salen el blanco o el gris para no escribir blanco sobre blanco hago que los cambie a uno de los colores del 11 al 15 que no podían tocar
      {
          if(color==7)//si sale blanco lo cambia a purpura claro
          {
              return 13;
          }
          if(color==8)//si sale gris lo cambia a rojo claro
          {
              return 12;
          }
      }

        return color;

  }
```

El resultado de lo que se muestra en pantalla sería esto. Espero que te haya sido util y que puedas guardar la función de cambio de color para hacer más bonitos algunos de tus programas.

[image: Imagen del resultado del programa]

Comment: Wow muchas gracias! Quedó muy buena!  Voy a guardar tu función y analizarla bien para entender lo que hiciste jaja. Saludos